# Execute Anonymous Function on page load

Tags: javascript, ajax

There are a ton of examples of loading a JavaScript function when the page loads (onLoad(), $( document ).ready(), etc.). The problem I have is that I have a function that doesn't have a function name, used to load a select statement based on the value from another. The code works (below), but it doesn't have a name ... I need it to execute when I load the page as well as when the value of the first select changes. I have been looking for examples and cannot find one. My Google fu is failing me. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
     $("#nameregion").change(function()
     {
        var region= document.getElementById("nameregion").value;
        $.ajax
       ({
           type: "POST",
           url: "namebranch.php",
           data: { 'myRegion' : region },
           //cache: false,
           success: function(data)
           {
//alert( data );                 
              $("#namebranchoptions").html(data);
           } 
        });
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out your anonymous function, give it a name.
Then call it via the change and directly on the document.ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#nameregion").change(getNameBranch); // this'll call it on change

     function getNameBranch()
     {
        var region= document.getElementById("nameregion").value;
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "namebranch.php",
           data: { 'myRegion' : region },
           //cache: false,
           success: function(data)
           {
              //alert( data );                 
              $("#namebranchoptions").html(data);
           } 
        });
     }

     getNameBranch(); // this'll call it on load
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful response. That solves it. I have a different issue, which is related, but not the JavaScript part so will post another message ...

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to move your anonymous function and give it a name:

```
function handleChange() {
  var region = document.getElementById("nameregion").value;
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "namebranch.php",
     data: { 'myRegion' : region },
     //cache: false,
     success: function(data)
     {
//alert( data );                 
        $("#namebranchoptions").html(data);
     } 
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nameregion").change(handleChange);
});
```

Then you can just call your function elsewhere in your code

Answer (score 2):

Since you are binding it as a change event handler, you can immediately trigger the change event to run it.

```
$("#nameregion").change(function() { ... }).trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to do is execute one function on page load and another one for another action, for this you need to define a named function.

```
    function functionName () {
      //do things
    }
```

After that you can use this function with it's functionality to execute whenever you need it.

For example one time when you load your page:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     functionName ();
   });
```

And then another time for the action you want to execute the function on:

```
   if (somethingHappens) {
     functionName ();
   }
```